# find if a value of Date exists in arraylist of Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

i want to verify that a Calendar Date not in a Arraylist of Calendar in java, I do this but it's not working for me :

```
List<Calendar> listFeriers = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startCal.setTime(beginningDate);
endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
endCal.setTime(endDate);
do {
    if (!listFeriers.contains(startCal)) {
        // Traitement
    }
} while (startCal.before(endCal));
```

Comment: Isn't your list empty?

Comment: Nambari is right, you have nothing to compare your dates against in your listFeriers. Now if you pre-populate the listFeriers list and then check you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Calendar> listFeriers = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
```

I hope you populate listFeriers somewhere.

You could just store the time in millis (getTimeInMillis) in the list rather than creating too many Calendar objects. You can use set to avoid duplicate time entries.

```
Set<Long> listFeriers = new HashSet<Long>();

if(listFeriers.contains(startCal.getTimeInMillis())){
    // A match..
}
```

Comment: _"...rather than storing the whole Calendar..."_ -- A list contains only references.